# Conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

Tags: c#, datetimepicker

I am trying to insert the date into a data table using a datetimepicker, this particular column's data as been specified as datetime.

Whenever I run my project I get this error:

> Conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

Here is my sql command:

```
'" + Convert.ToDateTime(MyDateTimePicker.Text) + "'
```

Comment: By the way, you can just use `MyDateTimePicker.Value`... it's already a `DateTime`.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably need to format it into whatever string format your database accepts for a time/date type column. For example, for our database I have to do `dateTimeValue.ToString("MM-DD-YYYY-HH.mm.ss.FFFFFF")` to correctly format a `DateTime` into the string representation accepted for a `timestamp` column.

Using parameterized queries (which are just a good practice anyway) might allow you to directly pass a `DateTime` as a parameter to the query. As you code stands now, the `DateTime` is being implicity converted to a `String` for you (by calling `ToString` which depending on your language/culture settings might be something like `2/17/2014 11:18:01 AM`).